# Why doesn't typescript consider destructured array variables as possibly undefined?

Tags: typescript

In the following code, I would expect the destructured array variables, `firstName` and `lastName`, to be of type `string | undefined` because the array being destructured could have fewer variables than the number being declared, in which case the additional declared variables will be `undefined`. However, typescript considers them to be type `string`. Why is that? Thanks

```
const [firstName, lastName] = fullName.split(' ')

// Typescript produces these types:
// const firstName: string
// const lastName: string
```

Comment: Well that would be a terrible thing if they did have it like that. But the good thing is, you ***can*** have it like that! Enable the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option and have all the fun in the world asserting things with `!` everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just the way the language was designed. For a similar example, you can do:

```
const arr = ['foo'];
const val = arr[2];
```

and `val` will be typed as a string - despite obviously not existing. This problem extends to everything with index signatures, of which arrays are just one type.

As of TypeScript 4.1, there's an additional config option available, [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess), that will result in all values taken from an index signature to have a union with `undefined`. With that on, your original code results in both `firstName` and `lastName` being typed as `string | undefined`. It results in more type-safe code, but can make some things a tiny bit more tedious when you're sure an index exists and always need to assert that it does.